# how to display Node Terms in block with tree structure in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I just enabled multiple terms for node creation and i just wanna display those mulitple terms 
as a tree sturctured in a block i tried with the following code

```
if ( arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) ) {
$node = node_load(arg(1));
if (module_exists('taxonomy')) {
    $terms = taxonomy_link('taxonomy terms', $node);
    print theme('links', $terms, array('class' => 'node-terms'));
} else {
    print 'No associated categories.';
}
}
```

But no luck its just displaying all terms, But i have to display like below

```
- parent term1 
   - sub term 1.1
- parent term 2
   - sub term 2.1
       -- sub sub term 2.1.3
```

Based on the user selected will display accordingly as a tree.

Anyone please help,

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Taxonomy Lineage module:

http://drupal.org/project/lineage